# cakephp 3 Cron Job not working in cpanel

Tags: php, cron, cpanel, cakephp-3.x

I am trying to implement cron job in cakephp 3 shell script but it is not working in cpanel.

below is my cron job code `blog is my cakephp 3 folder`

> cd /home/mmentert/public_html/abc.com/blog && bin/cake hello main

Cakephp 3 shell class file

```
namespace App\Shell;
use Cake\Console\Shell;
use App\Controller\UsersController;
class HelloShell extends Shell {
public function main() {
    $userinfo=new UsersController();
    $data=$userinfo->useremail();
    $this->out($data);
  }
}
```

Comment: please help ........

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are using shared hosting, the syntax suggested on CakePHP 3 Docs does not work for shared hosting, this is what worked for me

```
php -q -d register_argc_argv=on /home/public_html/bin/cake.php app main
```

Please use your own path for cake.php file

- -q --no-header Quiet-mode. Suppress HTTP header output (CGI only).
- -d --define Set a custom value for any of the configuration directives allowed in php.ini

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you, It is working great with me.
How can I set multiple configuration directives?