# Cron job not working cakephp 3 on godaddy server through cpanel

Tags: php, cron, cakephp-3.0, cpanel

When i am run command through ssh then cron will worki fine but not working through capnel. Throw the following eror

> Notice (8): Undefined variable: argv [ROOT/bin/cake.php, line 31]
>
> Code
>
> ```
> include dirname(__DIR__) . '/config/bootstrap.php';
> ```
>
> Context
>
> ```
> $_GET = [
>
>   '/home/ddule/public_html/bin/cake_php' => '',
>
>   'shellname' => '',
>
>   'methodname' => ''
>
> ]
> ```

cron command in capnel is

```
cd /home/ddule/public_html && bin/cake shellname methodname
```

Any suggestion.

Comment: Answered here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/42197260/1228430

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cakephp 3 Cron Job not working in cpanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38343673/cakephp-3-cron-job-not-working-in-cpanel)

Answer (score -1):

Try to enable shall access of your account and check this again.